# Finding an angle of triangle inside a 3, 7, 8 triangle

Tags: geometry

> Triangle $ABC$ is given with $|AB|=3$, $|AC|=7$ and $|BC|=8$. Points $P$, $Q$, and $T$ are chosen on the sides $|AB|$, $|AC|$ and $|BC|$ of triangle $ABC$, respectively. It is given that $|AP|=|AQ|=1$, $|BP|=|BT|=2$ and $|CQ|=|CT|=6$. Find the measure of angle $<PQT$.

I have solved this easily using cosine rule and the answer is 60 degrees. But I really would like to learn a geometric solution for this.
I was trying to figure out the relation between sides of triangle ABC and its inscribed circle, which is exactly the circumscribed circle of PQT.

Comment: If you want to avoid cosine rule, there's a solution using Heron's formula. But the first one is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\angle PQT=\frac12(180^\circ-\angle ABC)$ and the latter is equal to $60^\circ$ by cosine theorem.

Comment: The OP already did it with the cosine th.  The OP is asking for a *different* way to solve (if there is one).

Comment: @fleablood I doubt that there can be a way to solve the problem without applying the cosine theorem since the relation given in the answer is valid for any triangle, but $\angle ABC=60^\circ$ is a specific property of the given one (due to the side lengths). I also do not know how exactly the cosine rule was applied by OP.